# Log4j2 cannot get env. variable

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've checked a lot similar questions and documentation but still don't 
find any solution.

I have env variable. But I **cannot get this variable in log4j2.xml**.

```
<Properties>
      <Property name="logPath">${env:XP_HOME}</Property>

     <!-- <Property name="logPath">${sys:XP_HOME}</Property> -->
     <!-- <Property name="logPath">$${env:XP_HOME}</Property >-->
     ....
</Properties>

  <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogFile"
                             append="true"
                             fileName="${logPath}/${logName}.log"
                             filePattern="${logPath}/${logName}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        ......
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

[image: env variable]

But I've also create test for this case and its working.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you do `fileName="${env:XP_HOME}/${logName}.log"` or perhaps `fileName="$${env:XP_HOME}/${logName}.log"`

Comment: this   http://i.imgur.com/2AgPpqy.png

Comment: seems like log4j fails to do the correct substitution...

Comment: yeap, any ideas why?

Comment: Please raise this on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker. You may have found a bug.

Comment: I just modified one of our unit tests and had no trouble getting a similar configuration to work on my Mac. Can you set the status level to debug in your configuration and post it along with the complete configuration file?

Comment: Can you provide the additional information requested in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1370 ?